# display the values using html5 local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- I am trying to get the form values and display the values using html5 local storage
- I have written html and js code but its not working
- can you tell me how to fix it..
- providing my code below
- i have put in the fiddle too

https://jsfiddle.net/r977y9zb/2/

```
code
$(document).ready(function () {
    function init() {
        if (localStorage["name"]) {
            $('#name').val(localStorage["name"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["email"]) {
            $('#email').val(localStorage["email"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["message"]) {
            $('#message').val(localStorage["message"]);
        }
    }
    init();
});

$('.stored').keyup(function () {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

$('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
});
```

Comment: Scott's answer should be followed in getting your code cleaned up, but your code does work. Your problem on jsfiddle is that you had opening and closing script tags in the JS section, and you didn't have jQuery included. Here's your fiddle with those fixed and working: https://jsfiddle.net/keliix06/ykh6ys3m/

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` uses the `.getItem()` and `.setItem()` methods for accessing and setting stored data. You are passing your names directly to `localStorage` with brackets (`[`, `]`) as if it were an array, which it is not.

As an aside, there is no need for your code to be wrapped in the `init` function, given that you only want to run the function once, when the page is ready.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        if (localStorage.getItem("name")) {
            $('#name').val(localStorage.getItem("name"));
        } 
        if (localStorage.getItem("email")) {
            $('#email').val(localStorage.getItem("email"));
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem("message")) {
            $('#message').val(localStorage.getItem("message"));
        }

  $('.stored').keyup(function () {
      localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name')) = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
      localStorage.clear();
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...I updated the code in the fiddle but when I submit the form still I am seeing error "error": "Shell form does not validate...providing my updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/r977y9zb/4/

Comment: @texirv your demos don't work because you aren't including jQuery. Look at error thrown in console

Comment: @texirv See my comment for the issues with your fiddle, but this is good advice for cleaning up/correcting the code in general.

Comment: @texirv I think you need to revisit your HTML form at this point. You've got several submit buttons (not correct) and they are outside of your `form` element.

Comment: @scott the other submit buttons are for edit and delete actions :(

Comment: @texirv Submit buttons are for submitting the form. There should be one of them and it should be inside the form element (unless you are using the form attribute, which you are not). If you need other buttons to accomplish other things, use the `button` element. Trust me, your issue now is your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is your event handlers are not inside `$(document).ready` otherwise the code works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});


function init() {
  if (localStorage["name"]) {
    $('#name').val(localStorage["name"]);
  }
  if (localStorage["email"]) {
    $('#email').val(localStorage["email"]);
  }
  if (localStorage["message"]) {
    $('#message').val(localStorage["message"]);
  }

  $('.stored').keyup(function() {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
  });
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r977y9zb/7/)**</kbd>

Comment: but I should avoid this error ``` Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted```. since the name I give as input should be shown in the place of the full name...can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: That has nothing to do with any of this code. If that is a problem I suggest you start a new question along with the relevant code that triggers it and show how you are setting the csrf up

Comment: so I can't show it in the fiddle or is there any other online editor where I can use this functionality

Comment: Not in sandbox no...since it is specific to your server side method for handling csrf but we have no idea what that is or how you set token in form or ajax

Comment: can you tell me how to display the names which we submit in the form in the browser...since I am new to js not sure about the code...it would be great if you update in the fiddle

Comment: In the place of full name and full name 1  inside p yag

Comment: Get value same way you do above...and use `html()` or `text()` to set content of element. Please try to keep comments related to current question/problem